# Is it allowed to ask a question about Data on the Meta site?

Tags: discussion, meta, scope

To win a hat I have to ask a question or post an answer with a Data tag. Now do I not participate in any site where that tag is useful, so I have a bit of a handicap.
I guess I will not be the only one, therefor, here a question about Data questions on Meta.

Comment: There are 105 questions on one of the sites where you are a moderator which have a tag containing "data". Are they not useful?

Comment: They do not seem to work for the hat, containing data does not seem to work, it seems you need 'data' solo.

Comment: This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community.

Comment: It does, it asks for whether it is allowed. That is seeking imput.

Comment: @Willeke no, it appears the purpose of the question is to get a question in with the [data] tag. The actual written question is just a guise. Even if there is a real question here, it's unclear. What does it mean to ask a question about Data? Do you mean SE network-related data, or data in general? Are you asking about questions asking for the community to process data for you? Data request questions? Questions about how to process data?

Comment: Practically speaking... It looks like I'm the only one who got a hat from this 

Comment: @Willeke The hat description sates "Ask or answer a question with a tag that **includes** the string "data" and have a score of at least 1 on the post" are you saying this is wrong?

Comment: I have an upvoted answer on a site meta and do not have the hat. https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1122/when-will-travel-se-be-available-for-querying-at-data-stackexchange-com/8452#8452

Comment: Child meta sites don't count for Winter Bash.

Comment: @CodyGray, I am pretty sure they do count for some hats.

Comment: @Willeke in the past, yes, but not this year, and it's always mentioned in the hat description. I [checked](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1692600/i-would-have-got-splunk?AccountId=5942028) whether you had any old posts that would qualify (if they were posted during Winter Bash) but surprisingly it's not the case.

Comment: @Glorfindel, not being a computer person I do not even know my way around the data related travel or outdoors questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no tag for it until you created it. *If* You can figure out a valid, usable reason for the tag (and yes, for doing this, we now expect to figure out and fill that up now) - it would be fine.

Doing it for just the hat feels like petty vandalism.

Even *with* a tag wiki exerpt, it feels like a marginal thing, and not really in the spirit of what the hat is meant to be

Comment: I feel they made the hat too hard for non computer SE sites. So that is my excuse. (Not going to delete this question for now, although I do agree with your answer.)

Comment: Lots of hats are hard on many sites, and some hats are impossible for many users because they cannot rewind time. It's meant to be a fun extra, not the core usage or goal.

Comment: It's a real shame to hear about those users who cannot rewind time.

Comment: Alas, most of us travel *forwards* in time